# Unable to open socket on port 80

Tags: c

Downloaded [this](https://www.embedthis.com/download.html?image=s3.amazonaws.com/embedthis.public/goahead-src.tgz&name=goahead)  firmware which is written in c for embedded devices to play with,  decompressed it and compiled the src with `make` as written in the documentation copied `auth.txt` and `route.txt` and navigated to `bin` folder inside the `build` folder, when I try to run the code I get this error

```
goahead: 0: Cannot bind to address *:80, errno 13
goahead: 0: Unable to open socket on port 80.
```

when I run `goahead-test` it does not show anything

Does this mean that I have to forward the port 80 on my vm
or should I use another port because port 80 is used by another process if so how do you define another port

Comment: We can't help you troubleshoot software. This is not the right place.

Comment: A lot of times the OS only allows root to bind ports smaller than 1024.  Try running the program as root - if that works you may want to change the program to be setuid.  Of course it is possible that 80 is already open.  Use `netstat -a` to have a look